# ggplot2 How to remove border line on x and y axes while retaining border outline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the black border lines on bottom and left while retaining the purple border.

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
dat.ex <- cbind.data.frame(xdat=c(0,.4,.8),ydat=c(0,.1,.2))
ggplot(dat.ex, aes(xdat, ydat)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = 'purple', fill='NA',
                                        linetype='solid', size=2),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(margin=margin(t=40, b=-20), hjust=0.5))
plot_grid(plot.w,plot.w,plot.w,plot.w,labels="AUTO",ncol=2)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egydL.png)

Comment: `axis.line = element_blank()`?  I couldn't reproduce the black line in your linked plot with your code.  Maybe you are using a different theme than `theme_grey()`?

Comment: You may also want to check what your default theme is. (For example, `theme_classic()` would result in the above plot.)  One way of checking is to run `theme_get()$axis.line`.

Comment: adding theme_set(theme_gray()) before plotting did the trick.